# Two-Dimensional structured array

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, structured-array

I am trying to construct a `structured array` in Python that can be accessed by the names of the columns and rows. Is this possible with the `structured array` method of numpy?

Example:
My array should have roughly this form:

```
My_array =        A B C 
                E 1 2 3 
                F 4 5 6 
                G 7 8 9
```

And i want to have the possibility to do the following:

```
My_array["A"]["E"] = 1
My_array["C"]["F"] = 6
```

Is it possible to do this in pyhton using `structured arrays` or is there another type of structure which is more suitable for such a task?

Comment: You can use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org)

Comment: @yangjie tanks, `pandas` look promissing. However, I have to pass these data through MPI interfaces `numpy` would be a good solution, since they are faster and easier to pass through the interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a recarray, you can access columns with dot notation or with specific reference to the column name.  For rows, they are accessed by row number.  I haven't seen them accessed via a row name, for example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(1,10,1).reshape(3,3)
>>> dt = np.dtype([('A','int'),('B','int'),('C','int')])
>>> a.dtype = dt
>>> r = a.view(type=np.recarray)
>>> r
rec.array([[(1, 2, 3)],
       [(4, 5, 6)],
       [(7, 8, 9)]], 
      dtype=[('A', '<i4'), ('B', '<i4'), ('C', '<i4')])
>>> r.A
array([[1],
       [4],
       [7]])
>>> r['A']
array([[1],
       [4],
       [7]])
>>> r.A[0]
array([1])
>>> a['A'][0]
array([1])
>>> # now for the row
>>> >>> r[0]
rec.array([(1, 2, 3)], 
      dtype=[('A', '<i4'), ('B', '<i4'), ('C', '<i4')])
>>>
```

You can specify the dtype and the type at the same time

```
>>> a = np.ones((3,3))
>>> b = a.view(dtype= [('A','<f8'), ('B','<f8'),('C', '<f8')], type = np.recarray)
>>> b
rec.array([[(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)],
       [(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)],
       [(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)]], 
      dtype=[('A', '<f8'), ('B', '<f8'), ('C', '<f8')])
>>> b.A
array([[ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.]])
>>> b.A[0]
array([ 1.])
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think I can work around the indexing of the columns. However, if i use `np.zeros((3,3))` instead of arange and reshape, I get an array that has two triples in a row: `[(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)]`. But I just want one triple.

Comment: `dtype=  [('A', np.float), ('B', np.float), ('C', np.float)]` solves the problem. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: swot  I am adding the row thing to my original post

Answer (score 2):

A basic structured array gives you something that can be indexed with one name:

```
In [276]: dt=np.dtype([('A',int),('B',int),('C',int)])
In [277]: x=np.arange(9).reshape(3,3).view(dtype=dt)
In [278]: x
Out[278]: 
array([[(0, 1, 2)],
       [(3, 4, 5)],
       [(6, 7, 8)]], 
      dtype=[('A', '<i4'), ('B', '<i4'), ('C', '<i4')])

In [279]: x['B']   # index by field name
Out[279]: 
array([[1],
       [4],
       [7]])

In [280]: x[1]    # index by row (array element)
Out[280]: 
array([(3, 4, 5)], 
      dtype=[('A', '<i4'), ('B', '<i4'), ('C', '<i4')])

In [281]: x['B'][1]
Out[281]: array([4])

In [282]: x.shape    # could be reshaped to (3,)
Out[282]: (3, 1)
```

The view approach produced a 2d array, but with just one column.  The usual columns are replaced by dtype fields.  It's 2d but with a twist.  By using `view` the data buffer is unchanged; the dtype just provides a different way of accessing those 'columns'.  `dtype` fields are, technically, not a dimension.  They don't register in either the `.shape` or `.ndim` of the array.  Also you can't use `x[0,'A']`.

`recarray` does the same thing, but adds the option of accessing fields as attributes, e.g. `x.B` is the same as `x['B']`.

`rows` still have to be accessed by index number.

Another way of constructing a structured array is to defined values as a list of tuples.

```
In [283]: x1 = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
In [284]: x2=np.array([tuple(i) for i in x1],dtype=dt)
In [285]: x2
Out[285]: 
array([(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8)], 
      dtype=[('A', '<i4'), ('B', '<i4'), ('C', '<i4')])
In [286]: x2.shape
Out[286]: (3,)
```

`ones`, `zeros`, `empty` also construct basic structured arrays

```
In [287]: np.ones((3,),dtype=dt)
Out[287]: 
array([(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1)], 
      dtype=[('A', '<i4'), ('B', '<i4'), ('C', '<i4')])
```

I can construct an array that is indexed with 2 field names, by nesting dtypes:

```
In [294]: dt1=np.dtype([('D',int),('E',int),('F',int)])

In [295]: dt2=np.dtype([('A',dt1),('B',dt1),('C',dt1)])

In [296]: y=np.ones((),dtype=dt2)

In [297]: y
Out[297]: 
array(((1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1)), 
      dtype=[('A', [('D', '<i4'), ('E', '<i4'), ('F', '<i4')]), ('B', [('D', '<i4'), ('E', '<i4'), ('F', '<i4')]), ('C', [('D', '<i4'), ('E', '<i4'), ('F', '<i4')])])

In [298]: y['A']['F']
Out[298]: array(1)
```

But frankly this is rather convoluted.  I haven't even figured out how to set the elements to `arange(9)` (without iterating over field names).

Structured arrays are most commonly produced by reading `csv` files with `np.genfromtxt` (or `loadtxt`).  The result is a named field for each labeled column, and a numbered 'row' for each line in the file.

Comment: can't format this properly in a comment so bear with me.  To carry on from your line 298 ...In [299]:  z = y.view(type=np.recarray)   then In [300]:    z.A['F']   or In [3XX]:   z.A.F   yields    array(1)  recarrays just add the capability to simply arry['field'] with arry.field notation so z.A.F  'looks' better than the slice equivalent

Comment: Yes, my `dt2` dtype can be cast as a `recarray` and accessed with `x.A.F`.  The more complex the dtype the better `recarray` looks.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for the discussion of the different possibilities. I was not aware of the possibility to nest `dtypes`. Maybe, I will tryout your last suggestion with the nested `dtypes` later.